# Send data from Arduino to C# through the serial port, accumulated sensor data

Tags: c#, c++, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

I am developing a project that allows me to send DHT11 sensor data through the serial port to my PC. In my PC I capture the data in C# code. The problem is that apparently the sensor record remains accumulated in the serial port. Something like this `25; 40` [temperature and humidity respectively] should arrive every 2 seconds, but I get something like that: `25; 4026; 4323; 54`

What can I do to get one reading at a time? Thanks for your help.

Arduino code:

```
#include "DHT.h"

#define DHTPIN 2
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

String temperatura;
String humedad;
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  float f = dht.readTemperature(true);
  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t) || isnan(f)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
    return;
  }
  float hif = dht.computeHeatIndex(f, h);
  float hic = dht.computeHeatIndex(t, h, false);
  String temperatura = String(t);
  String humedad = String(h);
  Serial.print(temperatura + ";" + humedad + "");
}

C# code:

async void getSerialData() {
  var date = DateTime.Now;
  string temperature;
  string humidity;
  bool getDataNow = false;
  serialPort = new SerialPort();
  // serialPort.PortName = "COM5";//Set your board COM
  serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
  string portNumber = "COMXX";
  ManagementObjectCollection mbsList = null;
  ManagementObjectSearcher mbs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_SerialPort");
  mbsList = mbs.Get();
  if (mbsList.Count > 0) {
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in mbsList) {
      Console.WriteLine("Description:{0}", mo["Description"].ToString());
      Console.WriteLine("Puerto:{0}", mo["DeviceID"].ToString());
      if (mo["Description"].ToString().Contains("duino")) {
        portNumber = mo["DeviceID"].ToString();
        serialPort.PortName = mo["DeviceID"].ToString();
        serialPort.Open();
        getDataNow = true;
        button2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(56, 228, 6);
        button2.Text = "Synchro OK";
        button2.Enabled = false;
      }
    }
    if (portNumber == "COMXX") {
      getDataNow = false;
      MessageBox.Show("Ninguno de los dispositivos conectados se identifico como sensor syncro", "syncro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }
  } else {
    getDataNow = false;
    MessageBox.Show("Ningun dispositivo ha sido conectado", "synchro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
  }
  while (getDataNow) {
    string a = "";
    if (serialPort.IsOpen == true) {
      a = serialPort.ReadExisting();
    } else {
      MessageBox.Show("El dispositivo ha sido desconectado", "synchro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
      getDataNow = false;
    }
    await Task.Delay(4000);
    Console.Write("datos sensor  " + a.Length);
    Console.Write("datos sensor  " + a);
    if (a.Length > 0) {
      getDataSensor(a, out temperature, out humidity);
      lblHum.Text = "";
      lblTemp.Text = "";
      lblHum.Text = humidity;
      lblTemp.Text = temperature;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: sensor data]

Comment: Check your Arduino code. What do you think appears on the serial connection if you call `Serial.print(temperatura+";"+humedad+"");` twice? You would see `temperatura+";"+humedad+""+temperatura+";"+humedad+""` on your serial connection. Do you see the problem? (If you have solved this problem, you will have another problem in your C# code: You would need to discard incomplete data. Data read could be incomplete for example when the C# client reads serial data while the Arduino is just starting to transmit the second/third/... digit of a data value...)

Comment: You could add '\n' to the end of your message then use [`ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on the C# side.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
Serial.print(temperatura + ";" + humedad + "");
```

To:

```
Serial.println(temperatura + ";" + humedad + "");
```

So that the readings come out as distinct lines.